# The measurement of "collinearness" of a set of points

Tags: c#, xna, kinect

**Background**

I am producing a physics teaching platform using XNA C# + Kinect. A user may set up a scene with objects, including:

- Sphere
- Block
- Plane

The obvious fun thing to do is to use different gestures to represent an object. Plane seems to be the easiest one so I intend to start there.

The flow of inputting an object is like this:

1. Choosing an object (through gesture recognition)
2. Scale the object
3. Rotate the object
4. Place the object

**My idea**

Here is my idea. We track 6 joints of the upper body:

- LEFT + RIGHT wrist
- LEFT + RIGHT elbow
- LEFT + RIGHT shoulder

If this set of points is collinear, i.e. both arms held horizontal, we will say this is a input gesture for a plane.

If my idea is to be used, then there is a need to determine how collinear the points are, for example, some algorithm which returns the "collinearality" of a set of points as a float in interval [0, 1]. Then I can say, for example, anything >0.9 will be accepted as a plane, allowing some room for error.

OR

Alternatively, the idea of "Template Based Posture Detection" sounds great, stated in the link below:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2011/08/02/kinect-toolkit-1-1-template-based-posture-detector-and-voice-commander.aspx

But from what I understand, this seems to be a generic learning algorithm for ANY gestures. I would tend to write something on my own to try out Kinect as a start.

**Question**

So... does anyone know of any existing algorithm that determines the degree of "collinearness" of a set of points?

Comment: "collinear" is a property - so it's an on/off thing - but what you can do is measure the angles between the "vectors" the arms are representing if you do something like take the vectors from shoulder to wrist...

Comment: You could try Math.SE (http://math.stackexchange.com/) for the algorythms.